# Counting views of certain page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing a library app using a php, html and a custom mvc framework that contains 1000's of books, I would like to show the 3 most viewed books on my home page (and various other pages).

I will be creating a module to show on various pages.

What is the best way to approach this? I'm not sure how to collect such information. I don't mind if the views are unique or returning visits, not really important.

My `favourite` table structure is as follows;

```
-------------------------------------------
id    title   category    author    isbn
1     book 1   art        joe       123123
2     book 2   art        jim       234234
3     book 3   science    james     456456
4     book 4   maths      sarah     653335
5     book 5   spanish    jim       34534
...
...
-------------------------------------------
```

Do I need to make another column in my sql table and store the views here? Are the views stores in a session variable? Just looking for a simple solution really.

Quite new to php/sql here so any advice and/or direction is appreciated.

Comment: You can use MySQL's aggregate `MAX()` function with `LIMIT 3`

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- I'll have a look at that function. How does it work exactly?

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/ which contains examples.

Comment: use google analytics to tracks every page views, returning or unique visits.

Comment: @user254153: how could google analytics be useful to solve the OP's question?

Comment: Google analytics can track all the activities of your webpage. Like how many times you site had been visited, how many visits are new and how many are returning. For more details refer to www.googleanalytics.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add an `integer` column (let's call it `views`). Every time a user opens a book page, increment that column by one with a simple `update` query.

Then you can retrieve the three most viewed book with the following query:

```
select * from favourite order by views desc limit 3
```

Comment: This would limit the tables usefulness, what if someone wanted to know how many views a book had on a specific day?

Comment: Thanks @Lorenzo this sounds exactly like what I want to do! How do I increment the views column when the page is opened though? I understand the select query.

Comment: @ZachSpencer that information isn't useful to me. I'm starting with the basics, thanks though.

Comment: @ZachSpencer good point, but that's not needed by the OP. You're expanding the original problem

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon its true, but it never hurts to help a novice out a bit more :)

Comment: @johnny_s The basic syntax is `UPDATE table SET column_x = column_x +1 WHERE column_y='something'` - Consult the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @ZachSpencer sure, then your problem becomes a little bit more complex. If you need to keep track of the visits splitted by day, you could start creating a table with two columns: `book_id` and `timestamp` (or `date`). Then you have more granularity to perform whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a "views" table with columns like datetime, book_id, and any other data you want to collect about the client. add a new row to that table every time a user accesses a view book page. Then you just need a query like:

```
select count(*) from views where book_id = ...
```